# Why the variable always zero

Tags: c#, linq

I found a very strange thing:

```
var PerformanceSingleList = TradePositionList//Compute the data for each stock everyday
            .SelectMany((o, idx) => o.Select(p =>
            {
                //default variable
                double CloseYesterday = TradePositionList.ElementAt(0).Where(q => q.Stock.Symbol == p.Stock.Symbol).Select(q => (double)q.Stock.Close).First();
                int PositionYesterday = TradePositionList.ElementAt(0).Where(q => q.Stock.Symbol == p.Stock.Symbol).Select(q => q.Position).First();
                int TradePositionToday = 0;
                if (idx != 0) //idx cann't be 0 otherwise, idx - 1 throw a error
                {
                    PositionYesterday = TradePositionList.ElementAt(idx - 1).Where(q => q.Stock.Symbol == p.Stock.Symbol).Select(q => q.Position).First(); 
                    CloseYesterday = TradePositionList.ElementAt(idx - 1).Where(q => q.Stock.Symbol == p.Stock.Symbol).Select(q => (double)q.Stock.Close).First();
                    TradePositionToday = TradePositionList.ElementAt(idx - 1).Where(q => q.Stock.Symbol == p.Stock.Symbol).Select(q => q.RealDesignTradeShare).First();                        
                }

                double Commission = Math.Abs(TradePositionToday) * (double)p.Stock.Close * C;


                return new
                {
                    p.Stock,
                    p.Position,
                    p.RealDesignPosition,
                    p.RealDesignTradeShare,
                    TradePositionToday,
                    Commission,
                    PLN = ((double)p.Stock.Close - CloseYesterday) * PositionYesterday + TradePositionToday * (double)p.Stock.Close - Math.Abs(TradePositionToday) * (double)p.Stock.Close * SA,
                    NAV = (double)p.Stock.Close * p.Position - Math.Abs(p.Position) * (double)p.Stock.Close * SA - Commission
                };
            }
               ).ToList()
            ).ToList();
```

But,  all the Commision in `PerformanceSingleList` are zero even `TradePositionToday`  is not zero. Furthermore, there is no such problem when I use my little sample data, only occurred when I use real big data.

```
 [61]   { Stock = {{ Symbol = 1088 HK, Close = 12.860000000, Date = 3/7/2016 12:00:00 AM, Vol = 0.0490939300240106 }}, Position = -562, RealDesignPosition = 67, RealDesignTradeShare = 629, TradePositionToday = -562, Commission = 0, PLN = -7227.32, NAV = -7227.32 }    <Anonymous Type>
    Commission  0   double
    NAV -7227.32    double
    PLN -7227.32    double
    Position    -562    int
    RealDesignPosition  67  int
    RealDesignTradeShare    629 int
    Stock   { Symbol = "1088 HK", Close = 12.860000000, Date = {3/7/2016 12:00:00 AM}, Vol = 0.049093930024010565 } <Anonymous Type>
    TradePositionToday  -562    int
```

Comment: Put a break point (F9) and  debug it.

Comment: Maybe your mysterious `C` is zero then?

Comment: @ ForNeVeR  `const double C = 10/10000` never be 0

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] for us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, `const double C = 10/10000` is indeed `0`. 10 and 10000 are both integers, when the division is done, the result is stored as int (common type) before being converted to C as double.

In case if you'd like to have the C not to be zero, you need to explicitly tell one of the value as float/ double type, by simply using this statement instead:

```
const double C = 10.0/10000;
```

or

```
const double C = ((double)10)/10000;
```

Comment: I believe you can also write `10d/10000`. Writing d or f after numbers mark them as double or float.